How to update package versions in Chocolatey's .config file?
I received a Chocolatey packages.config file with a set of applications I need to install. It is a simple XML file with the following overall structure:
<packages>
  <package id="..." version="..."/>
  <package id="..." version="..."/>
  <package id="..." version="..."/>
...

Now, while I want to install all of the tools, the file is a bit outdated and the version attributes do not point to the latest versions anymore. I would like to install the latest version of all the tools.
How do I call Chocolatey to update the version numbers to the latest version of each package?
For some reason, I cannot find this in the documentation. There is some information about calling choco config ... for some tasks, but they all appear to refer to editing individual values.
Also, choco upgrade packages.config does not appear to do what I am trying to do.

choco config is irrelevant and unrelated to the .config file, which is the result of running choco export command. Versions exist due to --include-version-numbers param and are fully optional.
To install latest versions, just remove the version parameter from all packages altogether. Use e.g. Notepad++ with regex like (?<!xml )version=".*?"  or this regex101 example.
If you really want to update the versions in the file itself, you could then use the choco export --include-version-numbers command if you install the latest versions of packages in a fresh installation.

Aah, I was missing the bit of information that the version attribute in there is optional.
